# [CFXPreferencesSearchListSource tryLock]

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm implementing ShareKit, and so far so good on iOS5.1 and 6.0, however 5.0 is giving me a bit of problems in the simulator.

Whenever I execute my actionsheet and leave the program (for example to launch Facebook in browser), my app will crash with:

-[CFXPreferencesSearchListSource tryLock]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x957e120

What is going on? Couldn't find any similar errors out there when searching. Thanks

Comment: Odd. Could you post a full crashlog please? I'd be very interested.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug of simulator 5. After UIAlertView dismissed, press CMD+SHIFT+H, the bug occurs.

In fact, it doesn't occur in physical devices. So don't panic

Comment: Oh man.. took me 2 hours to find this post and test on actual device.. I almost started to panic!

Thank You a lot!!!!